# How to upload example code of ESP8266 to arduino uno?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I am using ESP8266-01 with Arduino Uno... I am able to compile example code of ESP8266 with Generic ESP8266 module board with arduino ide but unable to upload it to Uno...., it is giving an error: espcomm_upload_mem failed while uploading the code to Uno

Comment: Note that you have two programmable processors: The ESP8266 and the Uno. Is the example you mentioned intended to be run on the Uno (connected to a ESP8266 with standard AT firmware) or on the ESP8266?

Comment: If he example is intended to be run on the Uno, you should follow Richard210363's suggestion: Set the board to the Uno, since that's what you're coding for and uploading to.

Comment: If the example is intended to be run on the ESP8266, then your wiring is incorrect, because to upload to the ESP8266, you need to connect it directly to your serial adapter. (Which you will need to read up on, to prevent frying your ESP).

Answer (score 0):

How the code is compiled is based on the board you have set in the Arduino IDE.

Before you compile and upload, have you switched the IDE to use an Uno board?

In the Arduino IDE try:
Tools | Board | Arduino Uno

Answer (score 0):

Esp8266 generic example will not run on Arduino Uno. Possibly your device is selected as Esp8266 from Device Manager as gurus said. What you need to run Uno with Esp is writing Esp8266 serial controller to Uno. Here is the [sample](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18575/send-at-commands-to-esp8266-from-arduino-uno-via-a-softwareserial-port). Good luck.